# How can I implement a custom error handler for all HTTP errors in Flask?

Tags: python, error-handling, flask, python-decorators

In my Flask app, I can easily expand the list of errors handled by a single custom error handler by adding `errorhandler` decorators for each error code as with

```
@application.errorhandler(404)
@application.errorhandler(401)
@application.errorhandler(500)
def http_error_handler(error):
    return flask.render_template('error.html', error=error), error.code
```

However this approach requires an explicit decorator for each error code. Is there a way decorate my (single) `http_error_handler` function so that it handles *all* HTTP errors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not the only one, one workaround will be specifying the list of the http error code you're catching and bound to **application.error_handler_spec**, and drop the decorators, like this:

```
def http_error_handler(error):
    return flask.render_template('error.html', error=error), error.code

for error in (401, 404, 500): # or with other http code you consider as error
    application.error_handler_spec[None][error] = http_error_handler
```

Not ideal and ugly I know, but it will work and I do hope someone else can come with a better solution. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'd seen that and wanted to avoid (a) listing and (b) using `error_handler_spec`. Is that really the only way (for now)?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, I do come across with the same problem, and after quite some research (probably like what you've done already), this is the only way I think currently. The other **decorators** approach somehow just won't raise the error, or you need to purposefully raise the exception which looks even more uglier

Comment: Too bad. I wonder what the design reason is (or if it's just an omission).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, I think this is more likely the design judging by Flask in its form won't handle the error code status unless explicitly defined.

Answer (score 31):

You can use the `errorhandler` decorator with an exception class rather than an error code as an argument, as is described [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler). Thus you could try for instance

```
@application.errorhandler(HTTPException)
def http_error_handler(error):
```

to handle all HTTP errors (which presumably means all HTTP error codes), or even

```
@application.errorhandler(Exception)
def http_error_handler(error):
```

to handle all uncaught exceptions

**Edit:** Having looked at the flask source code, there is a 'TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS' flag in the app config, which you can change (by doing for instance `app.config['TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS']=True`).

(Roughly) When this flag is false, exceptions which are instances of HTTPException are handled by the functions you've decorated with `errorhandler(n)` where `n` is an HTTP error code; and when this flag is true, all instances of HTTPException are instead handled by the functions you've decorated with `errorhandler(c)`, where c is an exception class.

Thus doing

```
app.config['TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS']=True

@application.errorhandler(Exception)
def http_error_handler(error):
```

should achieve what you want.

Since it looks like HTTPException has subclasses for each HTTP error code (see [here](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/exceptions/)), setting 'TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS' and decorating your error handlers with exception classes not error codes looks like a strictly more flexible way of doing things.

For reference, my flask error handling now looks like:

```
app.config['TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS']=True

@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_error(e):
    try:
        if e.code < 400:
            return flask.Response.force_type(e, flask.request.environ)
        elif e.code == 404:
            return make_error_page("Page Not Found", "The page you're looking for was not found"), 404
        raise e
    except:
        return make_error_page("Error", "Something went wrong"), 500
```

This does everything I want, and seems to handle all errors, both HTTP and internal. The `if e.code < 400` bit is there to use flask's default behaviour for redirects and the like (otherwise those end up as error 500s, which isn't what you want)

Comment: I tried this in Python 3 with latest flask from PIP repository. It didn't work out. Any idea why ?

Comment: In which case an HTTPException is thrown with a code < 400? I checked the Werkzeug code (https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/src/werkzeug/exceptions.py) and all the exceptions subclassing HTTPException have a code >= 400 ?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've thought about this, and it may be that in practice the case of codes < 400 is unnecessary, but in theory this was to handle redirects and the like (as discussed in the last paragraph of the answer) which have codes 3xx

Comment: links are dead...

Answer (score 6):

For me, the following snippets was not working :

```
@app.errorhandler(HTTPException)
def _handle_http_exception(e):
    return make_response(render_template("errors/http_exception.html", code=e.code, description=e.description), e.code)
```

But changing `HTTPException` to the real one, like `NotFound`, was working. Don't ask me why, I didn't find the answer.

So I've found an alternative solution which works pretty well:

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import default_exceptions

def _handle_http_exception(e):
    return make_response(render_template("errors/http_exception.html", code=e.code, description=e.description), e.code)

for code in default_exceptions:
    app.errorhandler(code)(_handle_http_exception)
```

(Found at [Github](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/941#issuecomment-118975275))