# what is error parameter in flask errorhandler

Tags: python, web, flask

I have a question about flask error handler.
When I want to handle 404 error I use this code:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template("404.html")
```

Why I should pass the (e) to the function?
Thanks! :)

Comment: `e` is for your error traceback. And also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760113/how-can-i-implement-a-custom-error-handler-for-all-http-errors-in-flask

Comment: The `e` will hold the object of the exception that was raised so you can use it for contextual information to provide the *why* it failed in your return, or to handle it in your own logic on what you want to do on certain failures. This is explained in the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/errorpages/#error-handlers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e` is the exception raised, triggering the handler to be called.

You can register the same error handling function for *multiple error codes*, and you can use that argument passed in to determine exactly for what error it was called or use that code in a generic template:

```
@application.errorhandler(404)
@application.errorhandler(401)
@application.errorhandler(500)
def http_error_handler(error):
    return render_template("error.html", error=error)
```

From the [*Error Handlers* documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/errorpages/#error-handlers):

> An error handler is a function, just like a view function, but it is called when an error happens **and is passed that error**.

*Bold emphasis mine*.

Note that it is an *exception* instance; for HTTP error codes, that'll be an instance of a subclass of the [`HTTPException` class](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/exceptions/#werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException) (Werkzeug defines [several such subclasses](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/exceptions/#error-classes)). Such instances have a `.code` attribute if you really want to match against the HTTP code:

```
if error.code == 404:
    # not found error
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it is holding the exception so if you want to return it to know what went wrong. Though I am not familiar with this, or it if it is a parent it may need an argument supplied to it to check the error and handle it properly.

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer, its just the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The errorhandler is a decorator that is used to register a function given an error code, which can be an integer for the handler(like in this case code 404, or 500 etc) or an arbitrary exception.
In this case, you can return the error like so:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template("404.html"), 404
```

However, there may be cases when you would want to create a custom exception class for example:

```
Class ValidationError(ValueError):
    pass
```

In this case, if you want to handle the exception and also show the response to the client, you may need to specify them on the return value like so:

```
@app.errorhandler(ValidationError)
def validation_error(e):
    return e.args
```